# In linux, whose data does malloc give you?

Tags: linux, malloc, glibc

When you malloc memory in linux, it is not guaranteed to be zero'ed according to the specs. So whose data do you get instead?

Answer (score 5):

You get "whatever". If the process had previously allocated and freed memory, often it'll be at least partially filled with old stuff. Sometimes the memory will be filled with garbage specifically to make bugs more obvious. What you will NOT get, is some other process' old data; that would be a potential security hole.

Comment: Can you explain more at a low level how and when linux/glibc fills the malloc'ed memory with garbage?  It seems you would notice that from a performance point of view.

Comment: glibc won't do it for you (though it does have a debug mode which can be manually enabled, and which certainly does slow things down). Programmers will generally use a different implementation of `malloc()` to get this sort of behavior. Incidentally, though, it's not much of a performance hit -- setting a lot of bytes to the same value is something that processors can do *really, really fast*.

Comment: So what data do you get if you ask for more than you have previously allocated and freed?

Comment: If there's unallocated memory at the end of the process heap, sometimes it'll still contain data from earlier in the execution. Otherwise, it'll probably be (mostly) zeroed.

Comment: If you're interested in this stuff, the source code for `malloc()` is of course available, and (IIRC) it's actually not that difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks. malloc.c is 162KB of source code which seems a little intimidating.

Comment: The trick is, that if you need more memory than you "ever had before" the OS will give you some which was potentially used by another process (or even page out parts of your process if there is not enough RAM free). As mentioned above, the OS will erase it (probably with zeros, but anything is allowed) for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: It is *your* data. (from the moment you see it) It is up to you to do whatever you wish to with it.

The nature of your question is: Whose data was it before? Who written it there? And this is not an easy question to answer, as the tracking data was already lost. Inspecting the data itself may give you hints, but that is just guess-work.

Now, how come? Physical memory is divided (logically) in pages, which MMU (Memory Management Unit - part of your CPU) gives to processes living in virtual memory, on demand. Processes can then fill the pages with data. When the process dies, its memory pages are reclaimed to be unused anymore and are free to be supplied to other processes when they need a memory page to be present in virtual memory. But these pages are not wiped clean before - they are given as is. So the new process will see all the bits as set by the previous owner. But all traces of the previous owner itself are already gone...

Notice, that I didn't mention `malloc()` at all yet. This is because, so called, memory allocator does not take a part at all in this process. `malloc()` is just your private, in-process thing that does not concern physical level memory pages tracking. Bare in mind, that all processes have the whole available address space (the whole 4GB and up) to use. Even when there is not as much physical memory in the machine. That's why it is called virtual. And even if you have i.e. 32GB of memory in your machine, spawn 10 processes and you just went over your physical memory with summed-up virtual memory. But back to `malloc()`: your process needs a way of remembering which parts of memory it actually uses and which not. Of course if your requirements are static, you can just say that this structure is here, and that structure is there. But when you are creating memory structures on demand? That's where memory allocator library function (usually already in your standard C library) comes to play. It track used blocks of memory for you and can give you a pointer to some unused memory part. But this (virtual) memory is already there. It may have no physical page attached, but it will when you actually try accessing it.

`malloc()` could also point you to a memory area your process was already using and marked it as not used anymore by `free()` call. Then it is still *your* data. If you were writing to that area, this is the bits *you* set.

And we made a full round.

Answer (score 0):

Both [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and `free` are related to virtual memory, and they use the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap(2)` (and perhaps `sbrk`) syscalls.

But using these syscalls is somehow expensive.

So `malloc`try hard to reuse *previously* `free`-d memory zones (to avoid making too much `mmap` & `munumap` syscalls), and that memory contains arbitrary data (called garbage). Likewise, `free` don't release memory to the kernel (using `munmap`) but just remember that the memory you have `free`-d is later reusable (by `malloc`) It is data which has previously been used (and filled) by your own application.

Take advantage that Linux is free software and study the implementation of `malloc`  &  `free` in [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

Comment: Thank you. So the performance of malloc is really not deterministic it seems and in particular might all of a sudden take linear time in the amount of memory you allocate?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options what might happen.

Imagine a process which constantly `malloc()`s and `free()`s.

The first `malloc()`s start getting more memory from the OS. This memory is most likely filled with 0. You use it (put some data in it) and eventually free it again.

Now following can happen:

- Either the memory sits at the end of the heap and can be freed with `sbrk()`. This happens only if there is enough to free, as freeing is quite expensive in terms of performance. The amount of data which must be free at the end of the heap is related to the `mallopt()` option `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD`.
- If, however, the memory is not released immediately, but added to the list of free memory blocks, it (or parts of it) might be returned by a later call to `malloc()`. In this case, data you put here before could be read out from there (if there was any point of doing so).